# Error "malformed patch at line" when patching file with .diff

Tags: debian, patch

I having some trouble adding .diff patch to a file. Patch file itself seems to be fine but it keeps giving error:

```
root@pipiripi:/home/tomek/mad# patch mifare-mad.pl < pastie1.diff
patching file mifare-mad.pl
patch: **** malformed patch at line 434:
```

And the code of patch is:

```
--- mifare-mad.pl   2011-02-06 08:41:06.000000000 +0100
+++ mifare-mad.pl   2012-06-28 10:59:36.000000000 +0200
@@ -7,16 +7,20 @@
 # MIFARE Application Directory (MAD)
 # http://www.nxp.com/acrobat_download2/other/identification/MAD_overview.pdf

-use Data::Dump qw(dump);
+use Data::Dumper;

 my $debug = $ENV{DEBUG} || 0;

 my $function_clusters;
 my $mad_id;
+my $wkm_ttid;
+my $wkm_pos;
+my $wkm_line;

 while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    next if m/^#?\s*$/;
+   $_=~s/\s+#.*//;
    my ( $code, $function ) = split(/\s+/,$_,2);
    my $h = '[0-9A-F]';
    if ( $code =~ m/^($h{2})-($h{2})$/ ) {
@@ -25,6 +29,15 @@
        }
    } elsif ( $code =~ m/^($h{2})$/ ) {
        $function_clusters->{ lc $code } = $function;
+   } elsif ( $code =~ m/^WKM_TTID:($h{2})$/i ) {
+       my (undef,$ttid) = split(/:/,$code,2);
+       $wkm_ttid->{lc $ttid}=$function;
+   } elsif ( $code =~ m/^WKM_POS:($h{2})$/i ) {
+       my (undef,$pos) = split(/:/,$code,2);
+       $wkm_pos->{lc $pos}=$function;
+   } elsif ( $code =~ m/^WKM_LINE:(\d+|\d+x\d+)$/i ) {
+       my (undef,$line) = split(/:/,$code,2);
+       $wkm_line->{lc $line}=$function;
    } elsif ( $code =~ m/^($h{4})$/ ) {
        $mad_id->{ lc $1 } = $function;
    } else {
@@ -32,6 +45,10 @@
    }
 }

+sub bin2dec {
+    return unpack("N", pack("B32", substr("0" x 32 . shift, -32)));
+}
+
 my $access_condition_data = {
 0b000 => 'R:AB W:AB I:AB DTR:AB transport conf',
 0b010 => 'R:AB W:-- I:-- DTR:-- r/w block',
@@ -62,8 +79,10 @@


 if ( $debug ) {
-   warn "# function_clusters ",dump($function_clusters);
-   warn "# mad_id ", dump($mad_id);
+   warn "# function_clusters ",Dumper($function_clusters);
+   warn "# mad_id ", Dumper($mad_id);
+   warn "# wkm_ttid ", Dumper($wkm_ttid);
+   warn "# wkm_line ", Dumper($wkm_line);
 }

 local $/ = undef;
@@ -76,6 +95,9 @@

 my $pos = 0;

+my $wkm=0;
+my $zdm=0;
+
 foreach my $sector ( 0 .. 39 ) {

    my $blocks = $sector < 32 ? 4 : 16;
@@ -151,6 +173,7 @@
        ;

    my $condition = '';
+
    foreach my $j ( 0 .. $blocks - 1 ) {
        my $offset = $pos + $j * 0x10;
        my $block = substr($card, $offset, 0x10);
@@ -188,6 +211,7 @@

        my $hex = unpack('H*',$block);
        $hex =~ s/(....)/$1 /g;
+       $hex =~ s/0000/..../g; #/k./

        if ( $ENV{SWAP} ) {
            my $hex_sw = unpack('h*',$block);
@@ -196,6 +220,100 @@
        }

        printf "%x %03x  %s%s\n", $j, $offset, $hex, $condition;
+
+       # -----------------
+
+       if ($sector == 1 and $j == 0 and substr($block,0,1) eq "\x10") {
+           $wkm = 1;
+           my (undef,$ttid,undef,$pos,undef) = unpack('H2 H2 H8 H2 H*',$block);
+           my ($card_b1, $card_b2, $card_b3, $card_b4) = unpack('H2 H2 H2 H2',substr($card,0,4));
+           printf "# WKM: karta nr %03d %08d\n# WKM: [numer kontraktu %d] %s (%s) POS: %s\n", hex($card_b4), hex($card_b3 . $card_b2 . $card_b1), hex($ttid), ($wkm_ttid->{$ttid})?$wkm_ttid->{$ttid}:'kontrakt nieznany', (hex($ttid)%2==1)?'stara taryfa':'nowa taryfa',($wkm_pos->{$pos})?$wkm_pos->{$pos}:$pos;
+       }
+
+       if ($wkm and $sector == 1 and $j == 1) {
+           my $selector = unpack('H*',substr($block,0,1));
+           printf "# WKM: ostatnie skasowanie w sektorze %s\n", $selector+2;
+       }
+
+       if ($wkm and ($sector == 2 or $sector == 3) and $j == 0 and substr($block,0,1) eq "\x10") {
+           my (undef,$ti,$ty,$tm,$td,$th,$tt,$vy,$vm,$vd,$vh,$vt,$vl,$vb,$vs)=unpack('A8 A8 A7 A4 A5 A5 A6 A7 A4 A5 A5 A6 A14 A10 A*',unpack('B*',$block));
+           # print Dumper($tt,$ti,$ty,$tm,$td,$th,$tt,$vy,$vm,$vd,$vh,$vt,$vl,$vb,$vs);
+           printf "# WKM: [skasowanie %d]\n# WKM:   kontrakt wazny do: 20%02d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d\n# WKM:   bilet skasowany w: 20%02d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d linia: %s %s: %s%s\n", 
+               &bin2dec($ti),
+               &bin2dec($ty),
+               &bin2dec($tm),
+               &bin2dec($td),
+               &bin2dec($th),
+               &bin2dec($tt),
+               &bin2dec($vy),
+               &bin2dec($vm),
+               &bin2dec($vd),
+               &bin2dec($vh),
+               &bin2dec($vt),
+               # &bin2dec($vl),
+               ($wkm_line->{&bin2dec($vl)})?$wkm_line->{&bin2dec($vl)}:&bin2dec($vl),
+               # &bin2dec($vb),
+               ($wkm_line->{(&bin2dec($vl).'x'.&bin2dec($vb))})?'stacja':'brygada',
+               ($wkm_line->{(&bin2dec($vl).'x'.&bin2dec($vb))})?$wkm_line->{(&bin2dec($vl).'x'.&bin2dec($vb))}:&bin2dec($vb),
+               ($vs>0)?(' extra dane: '.&bin2dec($vs)):'';
+       }
+
+       # -----------------
+
+       if ($sector == 7 and $j == 0 and substr($block,0,2) eq "\x01\x01") {
+           $zdm = 1;
+           my (undef, # trailer \x01\x01
+               $loadno,
+               undef, # always \x00
+               $loadday,
+               $loadmonth,
+               $loadyear,
+               $validday,
+               $validmonth,
+               $validyear,
+               $pos_group,
+               $pos_no,
+               $unknown1,
+               $unknown2) # ???
+               = unpack('v c c c c v c c v c c H2 H2', $block);
+           printf "# ZDM: karta zaladowana %d raz, data ladowania: %04d/%02d/%02d, data waznosci %04d/%02d/%02d, punkt sprzedazy: %03d\\%d extra 2 bajty: %s %s\n", $loadno, $loadyear, $loadmonth, $loadday, $validyear, $validmonth, $validday, $pos_no, $pos_group, $unknown1, $unknown2;
+       }
+
+       if ($zdm and $sector == 7 and ($j == 1 or $j == 2)) {
+           my ($credits1,
+               $const_0000,
+               $checksum,
+               $const_ffff,
+               $credits2,
+               $const_000000ff00ff)
+               = unpack ('v H4 v H4 v H12', $block);
+           printf "# ZDM: Unexpected value %s - should be 0000\n", $const_0000 if $const_0000 ne '0000';
+           printf "# ZDM: Unexpected value %s - should be ffff\n", $const_ffff if $const_ffff ne 'ffff';
+           printf "# ZDM: Unexpected value %s - should be 000000ff00ff\n", $const_000000ff00ff if $const_000000ff00ff ne '000000ff00ff';
+           printf "# ZDM: Credits mismatch\n" if $credits1 ne $credits2;
+           printf "# ZDM: Verify mismatch\n" if 65535 - $credits1 ne $checksum; # (0xffff - credits = checksum)
+           printf "# ZDM: [%s] %.2f zl\n", ($j==1)?'srodki na karcie':'wartosc doladowania', $credits1/10;
+       }
+
+       if ($zdm and $sector == 8 and $j == 0) {
+           my ($transday,
+               $transmonth,
+               $unknown1,
+               $transhour,
+               $transminute,
+               $const1,
+               $transno,
+               $transval,
+               $const2,
+               $transid,
+               $unknown2)
+               = unpack ('c c H2 c c H6 c v H4 v H2', $block);
+           printf "# ZDM: Unexpected value %s - should be 000000\n", $const1 if $const1 ne '000000';
+           printf "# ZDM: Unexpected value %s - should be 0000\n", $const2 if $const2 ne '0000';
+           printf "# ZDM: [ostatnia tranzakcja] dzien=%02d miesiac=%02d godzina=%02d:%02d numer=%d identyfikator=%d oplata=%.2f zl, extra 2 bajty: %s %s\n", $transday, $transmonth, $transhour, $transminute, $transno, $transid, $transval/10, $unknown1, $unknown2 if $transval ne 0;
+       }
+
+       # -----------------
    }

    printf "KEY A:%s | %s GDP: %s | B:%s %s\n"
@@ -292,3 +410,243 @@
 887C - electronic purse MIKROELEKTRONIKA spol.s.r. MIKROELEKTRONIKA spol.s.r.o. Europe         4 01.05.2009 electronic purse
 887D - electronic purse Mikroelektronika spol.s r.o Mikroelektronika spol.s r.o EUROPE,Czech R 4 01.08.2009 Electronic purse

+WKM_TTID:00 czysty bilet
+WKM_TTID:02 bilet jednorazowy strefa 1, normalny
+WKM_TTID:16 bilet dobowy strefa 1, normalny
+WKM_TTID:18 bilet trzydniowy strefa 1, normalny
+WKM_TTID:21 bilet dobowy strefa 1, normalny (nowa)
+WKM_TTID:22 bilet trzydniowy strefa 1, normalny
+WKM_TTID:23 bilet dobowy strefa 1, normalny
+WKM_TTID:24 bilet trzydniowy strefa 1, normalny
+WKM_TTID:25 bilet siedmiodniowy strefa 1, normalny
+WKM_TTID:27 bilet 14-dniowy strefa 1, normalny
+WKM_TTID:29 bilet 30-dniowy imienny na 1 linie strefa 1, normalny
+WKM_TTID:2a bilet 30-dniowy imienny na wszystkie linie strefa 1, normalny
+WKM_TTID:2b bilet 30-dniowy imienny na wszystkie linie strefa 1, normalny
+WKM_TTID:2e bilet 90-dniowy imienny na wszystkie linie strefa 1, normalny
+WKM_TTID:2f bilet 90-dniowy imienny na wszystkie linie strefa 1, normalny
+WKM_TTID:34 bilet jednorazowy strefa 1, ulgowy 50
+WKM_TTID:48 bilet dobowy strefa 1, ulgowy 50
+WKM_TTID:4a bilet trzydniowy strefa 1, ulgowy 50
+WKM_TTID:53 bilet dobowy strefa 1, ulgowy 50
+WKM_TTID:54 bilet trzydniowy strefa 1, ulgowy 50
+WKM_TTID:55 bilet dobowy strefa 1, ulgowy 50
+WKM_TTID:56 bilet trzydniowy strefa 1, ulgowy 50
+WKM_TTID:57 bilet siedmiodniowy strefa 1, ulgowy 50
+WKM_TTID:59 bilet 14-dniowy strefa 1, ulgowy 50
+WKM_TTID:5b bilet 30-dniowy imienny na 1 linie strefa 1, ulgowy 50
+WKM_TTID:5c bilet 30-dniowy imienny na wszystkie linie strefa 1, ulgowy 50 
+WKM_TTID:5d bilet 30-dniowy imienny na wszystkie linie strefa 1, ulgowy 50
+WKM_TTID:60 bilet 90-dniowy imienny na wszystkie linie strefa 1, ulgowy 50
+WKM_TTID:61 bilet 90-dniowy imienny na wszystkie linie strefa 1, ulgowy 50
+WKM_TTID:66 bilet jednorazowy strefa 1+2, normalny
+WKM_TTID:6f bilet 20 minutowy strefa 1+2, normalny
+WKM_TTID:70 bilet 40 minutowy strefa 1+2, normalny
+WKM_TTID:71 bilet 60 minutowy strefa 1+2, normalny
+WKM_TTID:7a bilet dobowy strefa 1+2, normalny
+WKM_TTID:7c bilet trzydniowy strefa 1+2, normalny
+WKM_TTID:85 bilet dobowy strefa 1+2, normalny
+WKM_TTID:86 bilet trzydniowy strefa 1+2, normalny
+WKM_TTID:87 bilet dobowy strefa 1+2, normalny
+WKM_TTID:88 bilet trzydniowy strefa 1+2, normalny
+WKM_TTID:89 bilet siedmiodniowy strefa 1+2, normalny
+WKM_TTID:8b bilet 14-dniowy strefa 1+2, normalny
+WKM_TTID:8d bilet 30-dniowy imienny na 1 linie strefa 1+2, normalny
+WKM_TTID:8e bilet 30-dniowy imienny na wszystkie linie strefa 1+2, normalny
+WKM_TTID:8f bilet 30-dniowy imienny na wszystkie linie strefa 1+2, normalny
+WKM_TTID:90 bilet 30-dniowy na okaziciela na wszystkie linie strefa 1+2, normalny
+WKM_TTID:91 bilet 30-dniowy na okaziciela na wszystkie linie strefa 1+2, normalny
+WKM_TTID:92 bilet 90-dniowy imienny na wszystkie linie strefa 1+2, normalny
+WKM_TTID:93 bilet 90-dniowy imienny na wszystkie linie strefa 1+2, normalny
+WKM_TTID:94 bilet 90-dniowy na okaziciela na wszystkie linie strefa 1+2, normalny
+WKM_TTID:95 bilet 90-dniowy na okaziciela na wszystkie linie strefa 1+2, normalny
+WKM_TTID:96 bilet seniora, waĹźny 365 dni na wszystkie linie strefa 1+2
+WKM_TTID:98 bilet jednorazowy strefa 1+2, ulgowy
+WKM_TTID:a1 bilet 20 minutowy strefa 1+2, ulgowy
+WKM_TTID:a2 bilet 40 minutowy strefa 1+2, ulgowy
+WKM_TTID:a3 bilet 60 minutowy strefa 1+2, ulgowy
+WKM_TTID:ac bilet dobowy strefa 1+2, ulgowy
+WKM_TTID:ae bilet trzydniowy strefa 1+2, ulgowy
+WKM_TTID:b7 bilet dobowy strefa 1+2, ulgowy
+WKM_TTID:b8 bilet trzydniowy strefa 1+2, ulgowy
+WKM_TTID:b9 bilet dobowy strefa 1+2, ulgowy
+WKM_TTID:ba bilet trzydniowy strefa 1+2, ulgowy
+WKM_TTID:bb bilet siedmiodniowy strefa 1+2, ulgowy
+WKM_TTID:bd bilet 14-dniowy strefa 1+2, ulgowy
+WKM_TTID:bf bilet 30-dniowy imienny na 1 linie strefa 1+2, ulgowy
+WKM_TTID:c0 bilet 30-dniowy imienny na wszystkie linie strefa 1+2, ulgowy
+WKM_TTID:c1 bilet 30-dniowy imienny na wszystkie linie strefa 1+2, ulgowy
+WKM_TTID:c2 bilet 30-dniowy na okaziciela na wszystkie linie strefa 1+2, ulgowy
+WKM_TTID:c3 bilet 30-dniowy na okaziciela na wszystkie linie strefa 1+2, ulgowy
+WKM_TTID:c4 bilet 90-dniowy imienny na wszystkie linie strefa 1+2, ulgowy
+WKM_TTID:c5 bilet 90-dniowy imienny na wszystkie linie strefa 1+2, ulgowy
+WKM_TTID:c6 bilet 90-dniowy na okaziciela na wszystkie linie strefa 1+2, ulgowy
+WKM_TTID:c7 bilet 90-dniowy na okaziciela na wszystkie linie strefa 1+2, ulgowy
+WKM_TTID:d2 ??? 210 bilet nieznany - pokazuje wersje kasownika bez blokowania (pracowniczy?) - waĹźny 3 lata od skasowania
+WKM_TTID:d3 "przepustka na stacje metra" (pasazerska/HDK/70+)
+WKM_TTID:d4 "przepustka na stacje metra" (pasazerska/HDK/70+)
+WKM_TTID:d6 "przepustka na stacje metra" (SOM/policja/obsluga techniczna), waĹźny rok od skasowania
+WKM_TTID:dd "ZTM pass - karta testowa", waĹźny rok od skasowania
+WKM_TTID:e7 bilet pracowniczy ZTM, waĹźny rok od skasowania
+WKM_TTID:e8 bilet pracowniczy MZA, waĹźny rok od skasowania
+WKM_TTID:e9 bilet pracowniczy TW, waĹźny rok od skasowania
+WKM_TTID:ea bilet pracowniczy MW, waĹźny rok od skasowania
+WKM_TTID:eb bilet pracowniczy SKM, waĹźny rok od skasowania
+WKM_TTID:ef bilet dzieci z rodzin wielodzietnych, waĹźny rok od skasowania
+WKM_TTID:f0 bilet osoby niepeĹnosprawnej, waĹźny rok od skasowania
+WKM_TTID:f5 ??? 245 bilet nieznany - "poza dozwolonym terminem uzycia"
+WKM_TTID:fa "precode" (nie rozpoznawany przez kasowniki)
+WKM_TTID:fe "navette" (karta kontrolerska)
+WKM_TTID:ff admin
+
+WKM_POS:01 POP ZTM
+WKM_POS:15 Mennica
+WKM_POS:2a ASEC
+
+WKM_LINE:81 WKD # prooved
+
+WKM_LINE:91 METRO LINIA 1 # prooved
+WKM_LINE:91x1 Kabaty # prooved
+WKM_LINE:91x2 Natolin # prooved
+WKM_LINE:91x3 Imielin # prooved
+WKM_LINE:91x4 Stoklosy # prooved
+WKM_LINE:91x5 Ursynow # prooved
+WKM_LINE:91x6 Sluzew # prooved
+WKM_LINE:91x7 Wilanowska # prooved
+WKM_LINE:91x8 Wierzbno # prooved
+WKM_LINE:91x9 Raclawicka # prooved
+WKM_LINE:91x10 Pole Mokotowskie # prooved
+WKM_LINE:91x11 Politechnika # prooved
+WKM_LINE:91x12 Centrum # prooved
+WKM_LINE:91x13 Swietokrzyska # prooved
+WKM_LINE:91x14 Ratusz Arsenal # prooved
+WKM_LINE:91x15 Dw. Gdanski # prooved
+WKM_LINE:91x16 Pl. Wilsona # prooved
+WKM_LINE:91x17 Marymont # prooved
+WKM_LINE:91x18 Slodowiec # prooved
+WKM_LINE:91x19 Stare Bielany # prooved
+WKM_LINE:91x20 Wawrzyszew # prooved
+WKM_LINE:91x21 Mlociny # prooved
+WKM_LINE:92 METRO LINIA 2 # guess
+
+WKM_LINE:1001 Z-1 # guess
+WKM_LINE:2901 Z-1 # prooved
+WKM_LINE:1005 Z-5 # prooved (wk)
+WKM_LINE:2905 Z-5 # prooved (wk)
+WKM_LINE:1009 Z-9 # prooved
+WKM_LINE:2909 Z-9 # guess
+WKM_LINE:1019 Z19 # guess
+WKM_LINE:2919 Z19 # guess
+WKM_LINE:1019 Z19 # guess
+WKM_LINE:2919 Z19 # guess
+
+WKM_LINE:3001 L-1 # guess
+WKM_LINE:3002 L-2 # guess
+WKM_LINE:3003 L-3 # guess
+WKM_LINE:3004 L-4 # guess
+WKM_LINE:3005 L-5 # guess
+WKM_LINE:3006 L-6 # guess
+WKM_LINE:3007 L-7 # prooved (wk)
+WKM_LINE:3008 L-8 # guess
+WKM_LINE:3009 L-9 # guess
+WKM_LINE:3010 L10 # guess
+WKM_LINE:3011 L11 # guess
+WKM_LINE:3013 L13 # guess
+WKM_LINE:3014 L14 # guess
+WKM_LINE:3015 L15 # guess
+WKM_LINE:3016 L16 # guess
+WKM_LINE:3017 L17 # guess
+WKM_LINE:3018 L18 # guess
+
+WKM_LINE:601 N01  # guess
+WKM_LINE:6001 N01 # guess
+WKM_LINE:602 N02  # guess
+WKM_LINE:6002 N02 # guess
+WKM_LINE:603 N03  # guess
+WKM_LINE:6003 N03 # guess
+WKM_LINE:611 N11  # guess
+WKM_LINE:6011 N11 # prooved
+WKM_LINE:612 N12  # guess
+WKM_LINE:6012 N12 # guess
+WKM_LINE:613 N13  # guess
+WKM_LINE:6013 N13 # prooved
+WKM_LINE:614 N14  # guess
+WKM_LINE:6014 N14 # guess
+WKM_LINE:622 N22  # guess
+WKM_LINE:6022 N22 # guess
+WKM_LINE:624 N24  # guess
+WKM_LINE:6024 N24 # prooved
+WKM_LINE:625 N25  # guess
+WKM_LINE:6025 N25 # prooved
+WKM_LINE:631 N31  # guess
+WKM_LINE:6031 N31 # prooved
+WKM_LINE:632 N32  # guess
+WKM_LINE:6032 N32 # prooved
+WKM_LINE:633 N33  # guess
+WKM_LINE:6033 N33 # prooved
+WKM_LINE:634 N34  # guess
+WKM_LINE:6034 N34 # prooved
+WKM_LINE:635 N35  # guess
+WKM_LINE:6035 N35 # prooved
+WKM_LINE:636 N36  # guess
+WKM_LINE:6036 N36 # prooved
+WKM_LINE:637 N37  # prooved
+WKM_LINE:6037 N37 # guess
+WKM_LINE:638 N38  # guess
+WKM_LINE:6038 N38 # guess
+WKM_LINE:641 N41  # guess
+WKM_LINE:6041 N41 # guess
+WKM_LINE:642 N42  # prooved
+WKM_LINE:6042 N42 # guess
+WKM_LINE:643 N43  # guess
+WKM_LINE:6043 N43 # prooved
+WKM_LINE:644 N44  # guess
+WKM_LINE:6044 N44 # prooved
+WKM_LINE:645 N45  # guess
+WKM_LINE:6045 N45 # guess
+WKM_LINE:646 N46  # prooved
+WKM_LINE:6046 N46 # guess
+WKM_LINE:650 N50  # guess
+WKM_LINE:6050 N50 # guess
+WKM_LINE:652 N52  # guess
+WKM_LINE:6052 N52 # guess
+WKM_LINE:653 N53  # guess
+WKM_LINE:6053 N53 # guess
+WKM_LINE:658 N58  # guess
+WKM_LINE:6058 N58 # guess
+WKM_LINE:661 N61  # guess
+WKM_LINE:6061 N61 # guess
+WKM_LINE:662 N62  # prooved
+WKM_LINE:6062 N62 # guess
+WKM_LINE:663 N63  # guess
+WKM_LINE:6063 N63 # guess
+WKM_LINE:664 N64  # guess
+WKM_LINE:6064 N64 # guess
+WKM_LINE:671 N71  # guess
+WKM_LINE:6071 N71 # prooved
+WKM_LINE:672 N72  # guess
+WKM_LINE:6072 N72 # prooved
+WKM_LINE:675 N75  # guess
+WKM_LINE:6075 N75 # guess
+WKM_LINE:681 N81  # guess
+WKM_LINE:6081 N81 # guess
+WKM_LINE:683 N83  # guess
+WKM_LINE:6083 N83 # guess
+WKM_LINE:685 N85  # guess
+WKM_LINE:6085 N85 # guess
+WKM_LINE:688 N88  # guess
+WKM_LINE:6088 N88 # guess
+WKM_LINE:691 N91  # guess
+WKM_LINE:6091 N91 # guess
+WKM_LINE:695 N95  # guess
+WKM_LINE:6095 N95 # guess
+
+WKM_LINE:9002 E-2 # prooved (wk)
+WKM_LINE:9004 E-4 # guess
+WKM_LINE:9006 E-6 # guess
+WKM_LINE:9008 E-8 # guess
+
+WKM_LINE:9101 S1 # prooved
+WKM_LINE:9102 S2 # guessed
+WKM_LINE:9109 S9 # guessed
```

So I believe patch code is ok as it contains `+` at line 434. Am I using wrong arguments? What is the reason I get this error code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your patch is truncated. It's missing at least one line. The last chunk header is `@@ -292,3 +410,243 @@`, meaning that 3 lines at offset 292 are to be replaced by 243 lines at offset 410. There are indeed 3 lines of old text (the context at the beginning) but only 239 added line.

If you add a line containing just `+` at the end, you'll obtain a well-formed patch. There's no telling whether that patch is complete or whether the missing line was important or the patch is missing more chunks.

Answer (score 0):

what's about for this: (once I was able to patch mifare-mad.pl with diff file and it was OK after I added line with '+' and the end of diff file and now I copied both files from Internet and I added the same line and I got strange info:

```
patch mifare-mad.pl < pastie1.diff
patching file mifare-mad.pl
Hunk #1 FAILED at 7.
Hunk #2 FAILED at 25.
Hunk #3 succeeded at 32 with fuzz 1.
Hunk #4 FAILED at 66.
Hunk #5 succeeded at 80 with fuzz 1.
Hunk #6 FAILED at 158.
Hunk #7 FAILED at 195.
Hunk #8 FAILED at 203.
patch unexpectedly ends in middle of line
patch: **** malformed patch at line 433:
```

I checked both files and it should be OK.